# stripping a part of the url in bash

Tags: bash, sed

I have data that looks like this:

```
<b><a href="/title/tt3645068/"
<b><a href="/title/tt2741602/"
- <a href="/title/tt3173408/"
<b><a href="/title/tt1442464/"
- <a href="/title/tt2605802/"
<b><a href="/title/tt0103569/"
```

I am trying to replace everything before /title and replace it with https://imdb.com

I tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
sed "s/^.*href='/https\:\/\/www\.imdb\.com/"
```

Can you please help me correct this error?

Comment: `sed -e 's@^.*/title@https://imdb.com@'` -- beyond the notes in the linked questions about making handling of slashes sane, also note that `'` and `"` are two different characters, and putting one in a regex will not match the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> sed 's/.*\(\/title.*\)/https:\/\/www.imdb.com\/\1/' data
https://www.imdb.com//title/tt3645068/"
https://www.imdb.com//title/tt2741602/"
https://www.imdb.com//title/tt3173408/"
https://www.imdb.com//title/tt1442464/"
https://www.imdb.com//title/tt2605802/"
https://www.imdb.com//title/tt0103569/"
```

Comment: `sed '...' data`, avoiding the `cat`, will allow better error messages and involve less overhead. (The overhead reduction can likewise be accomplished by `sed '...' <data`, or `<data sed '...'`)